# SQLAlchemy ORM: create 2 attributes for the same column

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm working on the refactoring a legacy Alchemy ORM project, and for retro-compatibility reasons I need to keep some old attribute names and re-map them with a new name.

Alchemy ORM provide `column_property(attribute)` function that helps to create a **read-only** new attribute that reference an other attribute.
The other known way to solve this problem is using `hybrid_property`:

```
@hybrid_property
def price(self):
    return self.old_price

@price.setter
def price(self, value):
    self.old_price = value
```

Is there any more concise way to *alias* getter and setter of column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple mirroring SQLAlchemy provides [`synonym()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#synonyms):

```
class Foo(Base):
    old_price = Column(...)
    price = synonym("old_price")
```